# Reducing a system of differential equations to canonical form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have the system (where w is a constant):

$\dot x = wx+wy$

$\dot y = -2wx-wy$.

I want to reduce it to canonical form (which I'm not entirely sure what that means...)

From what I've read I need to diagonalise the system. The eigenvectors of the linear system are $\lambda = \pm iw$ and the eigenvectors are:

$(-1-i,2)^T$ and $(-1+i,2)^T$.

Thus I made the substitution

$x=(-1-i)u+(-1+i)v$,

$y=2u+2v$

But I don't think this gives the correct answer?

Comment: quick version, given the 2 by 2 matrix of coefficients, call it $C,$   you will be constructing $e^{Ct}$ one way or another. If you solve $C = P D  P^{-1}$  with explicit $P$   and digonal $D$,  the outcome is $e^{Ct}  = P e^{Dt} P^{-1}.$